# some conceptual issue on threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I need to calculate the time taken to execute each thread.
So I used this code to do it.

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,ts.Milliseconds);
Console.WriteLine(elapsedTime, "RunTime");
```

Now my each thread execute a method work(), this is how it goes:

```
void work(){
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    //codes,,,

    stopWatch.Stop();

    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,ts.Milliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine(elapsedTime, "RunTime");
}
```

So now my question is do I need to create an array of 1000 stopwatch objects or not because say 1000 work() methods are running concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work fine as it is, assuming each call is done on a different thread, as you are creating a new `StopWatch` object per thread.

That is, each `StopWatch` is not a shared resource, so the different threads should not be interfering with other thread `StopWatch` objects.

Answer (score 1):

If each work() method is spawned in its own thread, then yes.

On a side note, you probably shouldn't instantiate 1000 threads unless you have a really large server farm.

Comment: How would having a server farm help? The threads would still be local to the process...

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that StopWatch measures "Wall Time", i.e. te time that passes in "real life" between `Start` and `Stop`. When you have multiple threads running concurrently, the time will include times where the thread didn't execute but had to wait for a CPU core to become available.

[GetThreadTimes](http://www.google.de/search?q=GetThreadTimes+.NET) can measure time spent in a thread, but it isn't perfect either: it has a very coarse granularity (10..15ms), which makes it unsuitable for small-scale performance measurement, and gives incorrect results for threads that voluntarily give up their quantum early.

Answer (score 0):

Your `stopWatch` variable is a *local* variable within the `work` method. That means you'll have an independent variable for each time `work` is called... heck, you could even call `work` *within* `work` (in the same thread) and get independent `StopWatch` instances and `stopWatch` variables.